# PHP REGEXP match values to array

Tags: php, regex

for example I have this string. #345-6574#56-2432#776-246554#

I want to take all values between sharps.

I tried this but not working

```
preg_match_all('/^#[\d]+-[\d]+#$/',$string,$output);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex would be unnecessary:

```
$output = array_filter(explode('#', $string));
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/ZZH7B)

Comment: thanks for answer which is better for performance. regex or explode ?

Comment: `explode()` should be faster. It also is also easier to understand which makes future maintenance easier.

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
preg_match_all('/#(\d+\-\d+)#/',$string,$output);
```

You use lookahead and lookbehind as well if you want to make sure `#` to be at the both ends.

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=#)(\d+\-\d+)(?=#)/',$string,$output);
```

Comment: I need digits-digits in output array. not sharps. it returns values with sharps.